# Динамический заголовок с выбранными пунктами

Tags: html, jquery

Как можно сделать так чтобы в заголовке `СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЕ` отображались выбранные пункты
например: `Словосочетание: "Выбранный пункт из левого столбца" + "Выбранный пункт из правого столбца"`

```js
$(".child1 input").on("click", function() {
  $(".child1 input").removeAttr("checked"); // Снимаем чекбокс со всей группы
  $(this).prop("checked", true); // Оставляем выбранный чекбокс
});
$(".child2 input").on("click", function() {
  $(".child2 input").removeAttr("checked"); // Снимаем чекбокс со всей группы
  $(this).prop("checked", true); // Оставляем выбранный чекбокс
});
```

```css
.parrent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child2 {
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#word_opt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 26px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: #fefefe;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 19px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

:checked[type="checkbox"]+#word_opt {
  background: #7f2929;
  color: #fefefe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parrent">
  <center><span>словосочетание:</span></center><br>
  <div class="child1">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"   name="rand" checked style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">случайное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rand" style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">существительное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="adject" style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">прилагательное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="verb" style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">глагол</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"   name="rand" checked style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">случайное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rand" style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">существительное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="adject" style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">прилагательное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="verb" style="display:none"/>
      <span id="word_opt">глагол</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[пример](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbdGEN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предыдущий оратор прав насчет class вместо id и атрибута value. Но Ваш код для выбора при 2-ом и более выборе не убирает предыдущие выбранные. Вот мой вариант(вариант вывода текста можно исправить в функции):

```js
$(".child1 input").on("click", function() {
  $('.child1 input').not(this).prop('checked', false); 
  $(this).prop("checked", true);
  setWordCombination();
});

$(".child2 input").on("click", function() {
  $('.child2 input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop("checked", true);
  setWordCombination();
});

function setWordCombination(){
  let child1Text = $(".child1 input:checked + .word_opt").text();
  let child2Text = $(".child2 input:checked + .word_opt").text();
  $("#word-combination").text(child1Text + ' + ' + child2Text);
}
```

```css
.parrent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child2 {
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#word_opt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 26px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: #fefefe;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 19px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

:checked[type="checkbox"]+.word_opt {
  background: #7f2929;
  color: #fefefe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parrent">
<center><span>словосочетание: </span><span id="word-combination"></span></center><br>
  <div class="child1">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rand" checked style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">случайное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rand" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">существительное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="adject" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">прилагательное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="verb" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">глагол</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rand" checked style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">случайное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rand" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">существительное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="adject" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">прилагательное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="verb" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">глагол</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а он разве должен убирать выбранные варианты?

Comment: @humster_spb думаю да. Тут же есть комментарии: "//Снимаем чекбокс со всей группы //Оставляем выбранный чекбокс" Но первая строка убирает со всех лишь при первом выборе.

Comment: ну, это касается выделения. а в заголовке-то по идее может быть несколько слов: захотел человек прилагательное + существительное + глагол + ещё одно существительное. а у Вас только 2 элемента можно выбрать

Comment: @humster_spb именно так я и понял эту фразу: <отображались выбранные пункты например: Словосочетание: "Выбранный пункт из левого столбца" + "Выбранный пункт из правого столбца">

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, Вам надо заменить id="word_opt" на class="word_opt" (в css, соответственно, поменять # на .), потому что дублирующиеся id - это ГРУБЕЙШАЯ ошибка: идентификатор должен быть уникальным.

Во-вторых, добавляете своим инпутам атрибут value, куда записываете то же самое, что у Вас отображается в спанах.

В-третьих, создаёте переменную, в которую будете записывать передаваемые слова и выводить в заголовке:

```js
let spanText = 'словосочетание: ';
$(".child1 input").on("click", function() {
  $(".child1 input").removeAttr("checked"); // Снимаем чекбокс со всей группы
  $(this).prop("checked", true); // Оставляем выбранный чекбокс
  spanText += $(this).val()+' ';
  $('center span').text(spanText);
});
$(".child2 input").on("click", function() {
  $(".child2 input").removeAttr("checked"); // Снимаем чекбокс со всей группы
  $(this).prop("checked", true); // Оставляем выбранный чекбокс
  spanText += $(this).val()+' ';
  $('center span').text(spanText);
});
```

```css
.parrent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child2 {
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.word_opt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 26px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: #fefefe;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 19px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

:checked[type="checkbox"]+.word_opt {
  background: #7f2929;
  color: #fefefe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parrent">
  <center><span>словосочетание:</span></center><br>
  <div class="child1">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="случайное" name="rand" checked style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">случайное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="существительное" name="rand" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">существительное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="прилагательное" name="adject" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">прилагательное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="глагол" name="verb" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">глагол</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="случайное"  name="rand" checked style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">случайное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="существительное" name="rand" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">существительное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="прилагательное" name="adject" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">прилагательное</span>
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="глагол" name="verb" style="display:none"/>
      <span class="word_opt">глагол</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```